# NSOutlineView Control HighLight and indentation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview, nscell

In my Outline view, i am using CustomCell, which is nothing but took the code from Cocoa ImageTextCell RefrenceCode with some modification,

Is it possible to change the highlight color for a cell ?

So far i have done following, 
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {

```
if([self isHighlighted]){
    NSColor *evenColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:.1 green:0.1 blue: 0.1   
         alpha:1.0];
    [evenColor set];
    NSRectFill(cellFrame);
    bSelected = YES;
}
```

}

This is working but what is happening, i could see, hightlight cell color first start from system default color, then, it will get override by evenColor, 
I feel the problem is cellFrame.origin.x, its not starting from 0,

output was as below after applying this piece of code

```
----- My Custom Cell ----------------
======================================
| blue |                             |
| color|    even Color               | 
|      |                             |
======================================
```

and what i was expecting

```
----- My Custom Cell ----------------
======================================
|                                    |
|    even Color                      | 
|                                    |
======================================
```

Answer (score 0):

The highlighting is handled by the `NSOutlineView` (well, actually, it's inherited behavior from `NSTableView`). Anyway, instead of focusing on the cell, you should take a look at subclassing `NSOutlineView` and overriding [`highlightSelectionInClipRect:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000118-highlightSelectionInClipRect_). That's where you should do your custom highlight drawing.

Comment: it is not recommended to subclass from NSOutlineView (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)